# Server Error in C#/ASP.net application importing managed C++ dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have created a C++ managed DLL, which is linked to some unmanaged C++ DLLs. I am trying to import this managed C++ DLL to C# ASP.net web app. I keep getting this error:"Could not load file or assembly 'TessDLL.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found." Although when I link a C# console application to the same DLL, it works fine. Could anyone help me with this issue? I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: What is the functionality of the `c++` dll? I only _know_ `Console Application` and `ASP.NET` are different...

Comment: TessDLL(managed C++ dll) is a wrapper around some unmanaged DLLs which contain functions to perform OCR functionalities.

Comment: You could provide some code as to how you are trying to import the dll.  That would help in getting a response.

Comment: In C# project solution, I right clicked on references > add references. I selected my DLL and clicked ok. This added my DLL to the project. I could see the DLL in project bin folder as well. The C# project compiled without any error.

Comment: It's working now. I needed to give the path to the DLL in PATH environment variable.